# Databricks parquet write jobs resulting in empty files

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks, parquet

We have several Databricks PySpark jobs that write parquet files into the same container in Azure Blob Storage. Recently we sometimes get an output file with 0 bytes content even though the source data are there and it gets saved correctly upon rerunning.

Our suspicion is that the process first saves the output into the _$azuretmpfolder$ folder (which is created automatically at the top structure of the container) and when two jobs try to do it at the same time, it corrupts one of the output files.
(Something similar is mentioned in https://medium.com/@minfuyang/the-write-process-of-spark-azure-blob-writer-90b1bd373449 but in no official documentation.)

If our suspicions are correct, is there a way to configure the temporary folder (so that each job uses a different one)? Or has anyone experienced a similar problem and found a solution?

Snippet of used code:

```
(
    spark_df.coalesce(1)
    .write.mode("overwrite")
    .option("header", "true")
    .format("parquet")
    .save(output_blob_folder)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved out issue by separating the PySpark jobs (so that they do not run in parallel). No files with zero bytes appeared since then. This confirmed our suspicion about some unwanted interaction but we are still missing an explanation (if it was caused by the _$azuretmpfolder$ folder) or a proper solution.